# Why do mobs keep despawning even when named?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Mobs are despawning a lot, even if I name them. For example, earlier I got a horse and named it but when I came back it was gone.

Mobs are also just freezing in air, but it’s usually just sheep and chickens.

Why is this?

I’m playing on Mobile V1.16.101

Comment: Did you lead it (onto a post)? Did you fence it up? Did you trap it?

Comment: I fenced it in i didn't have leads

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities as to what is happening:

1. **You are using a very old device that cannot handle newer versions of Minecraft.** As more new features are added to Minecraft, it becomes gradually more difficult for devices to handle, as it requires more power (CPU, RAM, etc). Sometimes in situations like these Minecraft can glitch in this way.
2. **Your Minecraft app is corrupted.** On very rare occasions, Minecraft can install the improper way, causing ridiculous bugs and other issues. You can normally fix this by reinstalling the app.
3. **Minecraft has a bug.** This is most likely the issue, as [this issue](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-27535) has been reported multiple times to Mojang.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with my old console before. It either happens when your on a very old version of minecraft or if you have an old device. I was on a Wiiu and my minecraft slowly got more and more buggy until all of the mobs were just floating in air and not moving, despawning quickly. It may be for you that your device and the app file is corrupt. Try reinstalling minecraft. If that doesn't work you may need a new device.

Comment: Why would a new device fix this? (Not saying you're right or wrong, but no explanation is given)

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that one but I know it has to do with the device your playing on and not minecraft itself. The issue can vary.